# JQ - Groupby and concatenate text objects

Tags: json, csv, concatenation, jq

Not quite getting it.  I can produce multiple lines but cannot get multiple entries to combine.  Looking to take Source JSON and output to CSV as shown:

Source JSON:

```
[{"State": "NewYork","Drivers": [
{"Car": "Jetta","Users": [{"Name": "Steve","Details": {"Location": "Home","Time": "9a-7p"}}]},
{"Car": "Jetta","Users": [{"Name": "Roger","Details": {"Location": "Office","Time": "3p-6p"}}]},
{"Car": "Ford","Users": [{"Name": "John","Details": {"Location": "Home","Time": "12p-5p"}}]}
]}]
```

Desired CSV:

```
"NewYork","Jetta","Steve;Roger","Home;Office","9a-7p;3p-6p"  
"NewYork","Ford","John","Home","12p-5p"
```

JQ code that does not work:

```
.\[\] | .Drivers\[\] | .Car as $car |
    .Users\[\] |  
    \[$car, .Name\] | @csv
```

Comment: You'll need to `group_by` the `.Car`, then loop over each value you want to include, and `join()` them to your desired format before passing to `@csv`

Comment: What should happen if a car has multiple users? Or multiple users with multiple locations?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this:

```
.[] | [.State] + (
  .Drivers | group_by(.Car)[] | [.[0].Car] + (
    map(.Users) | add | [
      map(.Name),
      map(.Details.Location),
      map(.Details.Time)
    ] | map(join(";"))
  )
) | @csv
```

```
$ jq -r -f tst.jq file
"NewYork","Ford","John","Home","12p-5p"
"NewYork","Jetta","Steve;Roger","Home;Office","9a-7p;3p-6p"
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite optimised, but I though't I'd share the general idea:

```
jq -r 'map(.State as $s | 
    (.Drivers | group_by(.Car))[] 
    | [ 
        $s, 
        (map(.Users[].Name) | join(";")),
        (map(.Users[].Details.Location) | join(";")),
        (map(.Users[].Details.Time) | join(";"))
    ])
[] | @csv' b
```

- `map()` over each state, remember the name (`map(.State as $s |` )
- `group_by(.Car)`
- Create an array containing all your fields that is passed to `@csv`

  - Use `map()` and `join()` to create the fields for `Name`, `Location` and `Time`
    <sub>This part could be improved so you don't need that duplicated part</sub>

---

Output (with `--raw-output`:

```json
"NewYork","John","Home","12p-5p"
"NewYork","Steve;Roger","Home;Office","9a-7p;3p-6p"
```

---

<sub>JqPlay seems down, so I'm still searching for an other way of sharing a public demo</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Far from perfect, but it builds the result incrementally so it should be easily debuggable and extensible:

```
map({State} + (.Drivers[] | {Car} + (.Users[] | {Name} + (.Details | {Location, Time}))))
| group_by(.Car)
| map(reduce .[] as $item (
  {State:null,Car:null,Name:[],Location:[],Time:[]};
  . + ($item | {State,Car}) | .Name += [$item.Name] | .Location += [$item.Location] | .Time += [$item.Time]))
| .[]
| [.State, .Car, (.Name,.Location,.Time|join(","))]
| @csv
```