# JQ - Groupby and join using mapping

Tags: arrays, json, group-by, nested, jq

Submitted my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75474323/jq-groupby-and-concatenate-text-objects)  and had hoped to apply it to the bigger JSON file but I am just not getting it.

Using JQ I am trying to turn this JSON:

```
    [{"field": "F1","results": [{"details": [
        {"name": "P1","matches": [
            {"displayName": "User1","smtpAddress": "user1@foo.bar"},
            {"displayName": "User2","smtpAddress": "user2@foo.bar"}
            ]
        },
        {"name": "P2","matches": [
            {"displayName": "User3","smtpAddress": "user3@foo.bar"},
            {"displayName": "User4","smtpAddress": "user4@foo.bar"}
            ]
        }]}]},
    {"field": "F2","results": [{"details": [
        {"name": "P3","matches": [
            {"displayName": "User1","smtpAddress": "user1@foo.bar"},
            {"displayName": "User5","smtpAddress": "user5@foo.bar"}
            ]
        },
        {"name": "P4","matches": [
            {"displayName": "User6","smtpAddress": "user6@foo.bar"},
            {"displayName": "User7","smtpAddress": "user7@foo.bar"}
            ]
        }]}]}]
```

into CSV like this.

```
"F1","P1","User1 <user1@foo.bar>;User2 <user2@foo.bar>"
"F1","P2","User3 <user3@foo.bar>;User4 <user4@foo.bar>"
"F2","P3","User1 <user1@foo.bar>;User5 <user5@foo.bar>"
"F2","P4","User6 <user6@foo.bar>;User7 <user7@foo.bar>"
```

Cannot get the sub nested array to be respected by MAP.  Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: What's up with all the backslashes? Valid JSON must not contain them.

Comment: Removed them, sorry bout that. Artifact of the copy

Comment: Which part of the earlier answers did not work for you? The structure is identical, as far as I can see. Especially the answers which presented incremental approaches should be easily adaptable.

Comment: the sub nested array and the need to do multiple mappings.  I can get the first level "results" to work but the nested arrays: "details" and "matches" won't come back

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -r '.[]
  | .field as $field
  | (.results[].details[]
     | [$field, .name] + 
       [([.matches[] | "\(.displayName) <\(.smtpAddress)>"] | join(";")) ])
  | @csv'
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.  This iterates through the nested arrays for each $field adds .name and then joins the .matches values to one string.  Do you think this is more/less efficient then using map?

Comment: In both the C and Go implementations of jq, `map(f)` is defined as `[.[] | f` in builtins.jq